# OpenGL: How can I rotate a combination of two objects?

Tags: opengl, rotation

I'll simplify this problem with one example.

Imagine that I have 3 objects drawn in OpenGl:

> A Cube.
>
> A Sphere.
>
> A Pyramid.

I know how to rotate **all of them** and **each of them** in the same code. Just by using glPush() and glPop() functions, as you can verify in the code below:

```
glPush();
  AllObjectsRotation();
  glPush();
    CubeRotation();
    CubeDraw();
  glPop();
  glPush();
    SphereRotation();
    SphereDraw();
  glPop();
  glPush();
    PyramidRotation();
    PyramidDraw();
  glPop();
glPop();
```

The question is: How can I also rotate all combinations of 2 objects? I mean, how can I rotate, **in the same code**:

> The Cube and the Sphere.
>
> The Cube and the Pyramid.
>
> The Sphere and the Pyramid.

Thanks

Comment: If your decided to use the modern OpenGL, you would be able to 'bake' your own transformations in a far more flexible way than what you present here.For your question - just wrap with push / pop more than one obj to get both of them affected by the same transform.

Comment: Yeah, this also was my first idea to solve the problem. However, there is a big problem in wrapping with push / pop more than one obj to solve this solution.

http://pastebin.com/gV2RcVwq

There is a big error in this code.
I am drawing the Cube 2 times. One above the other. 

I don’t want to write the Cube two times. Also, I don't want to loose the information of previously rotations, so I want to rotate the Cube with the Sphere, and, after, rotate the result of the rotation of the Cube with the Pyramid.